# Why isn't my new dehumidifier running?

Tags: dehumidifier

I bought a dehumidifier today. It's an Izzy Avra IZ-9050 which they use here a lot maybe from Greece or Italy not sure. I can't find any information on this item only places to buy it and [online manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2491467/Izzy-Avra-Iz-9050.html?page=17). It's super easy steps. Plug in, hear it beep, push power, select mode.

Well, the beep sound happens, I push power, then none of the functions are working. Just a 23 stays displayed on the screen where humidity is. Nothing else will turn on or off, no fan sounds, no indicator lights turn on for auto or consistency. It's brand new out of the box. I can't find any YouTube videos either.

Is it defective or am I doing something wrong? Usually it's so easy to use.

Comment: periods at ends of sentences are very important ... `I started getting mold people`

Comment: why are you posting here?  ... talk to the manufacturer, or return the device for an exchange

Comment: Have you followed the directions exactly? https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2491467/Izzy-Avra-Iz-9050.html?page=21#manual

Comment: Are you sure it's not reading 23% humidity - mine, when it turns on, displays the current humidity. And that's really low, almost certainly below the default setpoint. If there's a down arrow or minus button, press that repeatedly and see if you can get into a continuous mode

Comment: ... And what is the humidity where you are now? If it's properly cold outside, mine doesn't run unless I'm generating water vapour, because the little outside air that gets in is so dry there's no need

Comment: Well there's no minus button says 23% but there's no way the humidity outside is 80/90% right now.  Inside is probably 50/60% . If I keep pushing the humidity button nothing changes.

Comment: It looks like the control panel has a clear right way up as there's printed text on it. Otherwise, 23 upside down on a 7-segment display is E2, which would be an error code.